# Homestead loses shared folders on each restart - Linux Mint

Tags: linux, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have Linux Mint 18.2 version. I wanted to install homestead (I know it's Linux in Linux, but it gives more control like that).

```
Download and install vagrant -> Done
Download and install Virtual Box -> Done
Run command "vagrant box add laravel/homestead" -> Done
Clone git repository -> Done
Run "bash init.sh" -> Done
Config Homestead.yaml file -> Done
Generate private keys -> Done
Add 192.168.10.10 to hosts -> Done
```

And now, I created new Laravel project. All working, browser loads homestead.app site, everything is fine. It creates the folder on my local computer like it should. Everything is inside. I shutdown the machine and started it again. **Only the root folder is there**. Empty completely. Ther are in the local folder, but not on the VM. There are no projects inside. They show up only when I run **vagrant reload**. But it works on my Windows machine perfectly. I tried deleting the machine, creating new. Same thing. Reinstalling virtual box, vagrant: nothing. Reinstalled entire system, fresh copy, all updated. Nothing. Can anyone help me, I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: what exactly is _I shutdown the machine and started it again_ so you do `vagrant up` you do not see the site, but if you run `vagrant reload` the sites show up ? what you mean `Only the root folder is there`. Sounds to me like you start VM from virtualbox directly so shared folders are not in place

Comment: Shutdown the VM machine. ACPI Shutdown, in the VirtualBox menu. Then I open VirtualBox again, start the machine on the Start button, and login. Only `vagrant/Laravel` is there. Inside were couple of folders before I shutdowned machine. Those folders are on my local machine in shared folders, but not in the VM.

Comment: Yes, that's right. On the first run, everything is running normally, but when the VM is restarted, it loses all content of main folder, which is shared with my Host system. Only when I run `vagrant reload`, those folders are again visible and usabe in homestead VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [vagrant doc site](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/index.html)

> Vagrant - the command line utility for managing the lifecycle of virtual machines

Once you or someone else creates a single Vagrantfile, you just need to vagrant up and everything is installed and configured for you to work

Vagrant completely abstract you from using VirtualBox, when using vagrant you should not start the VM from Virtualbox.

When you start the VM from vagrant, vagrant is doing its magic to configure hostname, port foward, shared folder and so on; so if you start the VM directly from VirtualBox, none of this is done.

just run `$ vagrant up` when you need to start up your VM server and your sites will be available